# RC5 NgModules declarations

Tags: angular, typescript

After upgrading angular 2 to RC5, i was getting warnings like below asking me to move my components to module declarations:

> NgModule AppModule uses AcademylistComponent via "entryComponents" but
>   it was neither declared nor imported! This warning will become an
>   error after final.

I was refering to these components in my router config file. What looked like this:

```
import {provideRouter,RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';
import {AcademylistComponent} from '../modules/home/component/academyList.component';
import {CourselistComponent} from '../modules/home/component/courseList.component';
import {CreateacademyComponent} from '../modules/home/component/createAcademy.component';
import {ReportsComponent} from '../modules/home/component/reports.component';
import {AuthenticatedGuard} from '../guards/authenticated.guard';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo:'/home',
    terminal:true},
{
    path: 'home',
    canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuard],
    children: [

        {path: '', component: AcademylistComponent},
        {path: 'my-academies', component: AcademylistComponent},
        {path: 'my-courses', component: CourselistComponent},
        {path: 'create-academy', component: CreateacademyComponent},
        {path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent}

    ]

}

];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
provideRouter(routes)
];
```

When i moved the components to ng module's `declarations` array and imported them there, the routes config file did started giving me `Cannot find name` errors.

So how do i use module declarations in this case?

Comment: can you show us the current code (NgModule) ?

Answer (score 10):

Even if you declare them in your routes, You still have to declare the components used in the routes in the NgModule.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AcademylistComponent,
    //.. and so on
  ], 
  providers: [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: According to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html: "For RC5, you can leave your components, directives and pipes in the directives and pipes properties of your @Component metadata...This option is temporary for backward compatibility. It will be removed in the final release of Angular 2.0.

Get ahead of the game and start moving your component directives and pipes into module declarations as soon as possible."

Comment: One quick question. If i remove a component/directive/pipe from a component's providers/directives array and add it to NgModule's provider's array, do i still have to `import ...` that component/pipe/directive in the component? I get errors without doing so. Is this right approach?

Comment: @TrumanCode Also, the link you refer to only asks us to do this practice for app.component. I assume, we have to do the same for all components in the app?

Comment: Going by the guidance at  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html - I'd say the answer is yes to both questions: you still need to import files needed for that module, and any "feature modules" you create also need to follow the convention of declaring components in the declarations list.

Comment: Yes, you only need to import them if you need to reference the component inside the code.